# Removing certain rows from table on condition plus converting varchar to date

Tags: sql, oracle

I understand that this question might have a trivial answer. I would like to remove certain rows from a huge table when certain condition is met. The condition is on `drdate` (a varchar field), which holds date information so it needs to be converted. The table is huge and ideally I do not want to spend too much time for the query to run.

```
delete from products 
where (to_date('drdate','mm/dd/yyyy')) > (to_date('01/01/2011','mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

This returns:

*SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000*

Comment: What datatype is in the drdate column?

Comment: The OP says it's varchar

Comment: Why are there quotes around the `drdate` column name in the code?

Comment: well spotted SchmitzIT. Obviously the condition needs to be turned around. Ok thx

Comment: @SchmitzIT So they do. I was asking as I'd spotted the same thing you had, but clearly neglected to read the entire question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete from products 
where (to_date(drdate,'mm/dd/yyyy')) > (to_date('01/01/2011','mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

As stated in the comment, the quotes cause the function to evaluate the string value **'drdate'** instead of the values in the `drdate` column.